# Bipartite graph with n vertices

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

Background: I am trying to use simple induction to prove that any bipartite graph with n vertices has no more than $\frac{n^2}{4}$ edges, and I find that the following question can be helpful here to help me finish the induction and thus complete the proof, but I get stuck.

How to prove that in a bipartite graph, you can always choose a vertex with $\le\lfloor\frac{|V|}{2} \rfloor$ edges incident with it?

Comment: One of the "parts" of the bipartite graph is at least as large as the other part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a bipartite graph, the vertices are partitioned into two "parts" such that there are no edges between two vertices in the same part. Thus, each vertex is adjacent to *at most* all the vertices in the other part. The two parts cannot both contain more than $\lfloor \frac{|V|}{2} \rfloor$ vertices since then the bipartite graph would have $> 2\frac{|V|}{2}=|V|=n$ vertices, which is false. So there must be at least one vertex with at most $\lfloor \frac{|V|}{2} \rfloor$ edges adjacent to it.